# multiple lines to a line in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

unprovision_meta_data xmltype column

```
select h.unprovision_meta_data.extract('/').getStringVal() from test h;
```

Outputs :

```
<Warehouse whono="200">
  <Building>Leased</Building>
</Warehouse>
```

I want in a single line like this:

```
<Warehouse whono="200"> <Building>Leased</Building> </Warehouse>
```

Basically I want to spool sql output to a flat file.so every row will be in a single line
will this be possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [`TRANSLATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) for that purpose:

```
 select TRANSLATE(h.unprovision_meta_data.extract('/').getStringVal(),
                  '-' || chr(10) || chr(13),
                  '-')
 from test h;
```

The `TRANSLATE(..., '-' || chr(10) || chr(13), '-')` part will:

- map `-` to `-` (identity operation)
- map `\r` to *nothing*
- map `\n` to *nothing*

The `-` trick is because `TRANSLATE` does not behave as you might expect when the replacement string is empty (it will return `NULL` in that case).

Answer (score 0):

```
select  regexp_replace(
     h.unprovision_meta_data.extract('/').getStringVal(), 
    '('||chr(10)||'|'||chr(13)||')+', 
    '') as unprovision_meta_data
from test h
```

outputs :

```
<Warehouse whono="200">  <Building>Leased</Building></Warehouse>
```